# Automatic menu for a UL tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

Is there a way to use jQuery to automatically apply a vertical accordion menu (or some other vertical menu type) to a UL tag? So, something like this could become a menu via a JavaScript call:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

In other words, its LI children would become menu items. It would be great if the menu's height could be constrained. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shown here on this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V3z6b/)  :-D

js:

```
$('.menu .menu-item').hover(function(){$(this).children('ul').toggle('blind')})
    $('.menu .menu-item ul').hide()
```

html:

```
<ul class='menu'>
    <li class='menu-item'> ITEM
       <ul class='sub-menu'>
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
         <li>Item 4</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't even need Javascript(*). use suckerfish: http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

(* I think only for an unsupported event in IE6)

Answer (score 1):

There are a **[ton](http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-jquery-menu-plugins) [of](http://designm.ag/resources/jquery-navigation-plugins/) [plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/)** for this.

**[Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)** is built off of the Suckerfish (css-only) menus, but adds a bit of javascript to handle some of the yucky quirks of a css-only solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new menu class in jQuery UI's [github repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js) that will be in jQuery UI 1.9 that should satisfy your needs.

It's compatible with jQuery UI 1.8,  and ThemeRoller too.

It handles nested sub-menus.  I've used it on a project recently and it's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I actually use AllWebMenus Pro (Likno Software) to make vertical menus and I'm quite contented.I think it will work for you.